# keydown event : how use preventdefault without break fire of change event

Tags: javascript

I need to intercept and replace chars in input text, so have the following code for keydown event handler for an input text :

```js
let my_input = document.querySelector("#my_input");
    
my_input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 e.target.value = 'toto';
   e.preventDefault();
   var event = new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true });
   e.target.dispatchEvent(event);
});


my_input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  //never fired even you focus out the input text
    console.log("changes are coming");
});
```

```html
 
<input type="text" id="my_input" pattern="^\d+((\.|\,)(\d{1,2})?)?"  />
```

What seems odd to me is that when focusout event is fired, then change event is never fired.

Do you understand what happends and how to make it work normally?

Comment: do you try to use `blur` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: Is there by any chance any other event that triggers at the same time ? I had the same issue once because the framework i used, trigerred a click elsewhere at the same time.

Comment: `The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.` - change is non standard event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: @ZakariaSahmane I have write code in vanilla js for a better  explication

Comment: @VivienPipo It seems it comes from `preventDefault`, by invoking it, you break the normal behavior of the input. Try to remove it!

Comment: There is no input event fired when setting values with .value = "todo" and because of the same reason there is no change detected. Input event is only triggered through user input, and since there is preventDefault it's not detected. (as far that i know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onblur` event. `e.preventDefault()` is causing your problem by changing the normal behavior of the `input`.

```html
<input type="text" id="my_input" onblur="myFunction()"/>  
<script>
let my_input = document.querySelector("#my_input");
var changed = false;
    
my_input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   e.target.value = 'toto';
   e.preventDefault();
   changed = true;
   var event = new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true });
   e.target.dispatchEvent(event);
});


function myFunction(){
   if(changed){
    console.log("changes are coming");
    changed = false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This would still allow entering other chars without intercepting them, this is the reason why he uses preventDefault. Indeed preventDefault is the problem and he needs a workaround it.

Comment: @OlivierKrull Yes, you are right. I changed it to `onblur`.

Comment: Hmm but this would log "changes are coming even if there is no change". e.g you just focus without entering anything.

Comment: @OlivierKrull I incorporated checking if the input changed by assigning `true` to variable `changed` on `keydown`.

Comment: @hev1 thank you for answere but i would like to put this behaviour on all inputs in my proj so your solution that nedds to add  onblur="myFunction() is too heavy for me

Comment: @VivienPipo What do you mean by that?